# Crop UIImage keeping the same Aspect Ratio

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app, where you can edit photos, these photos are displayed as `scaleAspectFill`. When I know want to save the photo the edited things are not in the right position. (The `UIImageView` name is ImageView).
This is why I tried to crop my image, but I don't really know which values I really should use, I tried many possibilities.

My Code Is:

```
func crop() -> UIImage {
    let x:CGFloat = ImageView.frame.maxX
    let y:CGFloat = ImageView.frame.maxY
    let width:CGFloat = ImageView.frame.width
    let height:CGFloat = ImageView.frame.height
    let croppedCGImage = ImageView.image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
    let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!)

    return croppedImage
}
```

I tried it with maxX/maxY too this is why it is written there.

---

#### Update

So I edited the image and now I want to save it, but now is really small, so it would be nice if you would help

this is the first image, how it should be
https://i.stack.imgur.com/91RBX.jpg

and this is the result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpDpY.png

Comment: You *may* be on the right track but not working the right way. Aspect fill *changes* the image size to *fill* the frame parameters - it also *doesn't* change the **image** size in any "way, shape, or form" (forgive the play on words). Can you give a *full* example of (a) the source, (b) the result, and (c) what you expected? Thanks.

Comment: did it look update

Comment: @dfd do you have an idea